# WPF: Rendering in "layers" (though this is the wrong terminology)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I recall watching a video from one of the recent (last 12-18 months) Microsoft events that showed a way by which you could control which controls are rendered first in WPF, thus making a scrollable list much more responsive because you only draw the critical part of the list entry first and then the remaining items are drawn when the scrolling slows or settles. I believe it was controlled using attached properties and you basically prioritised the various elements being created.

Problem is, I cannot remember where the video was or the correct terminology for this - thus I cannot google for more information. Can anybody give me some pointers please.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to something like [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc716879%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, but this is something new in (or around) 4.6; the example used was lots of tiles with pictures and titles - when scrolling, the titles would be drawn immediately but the images would only be drawn after scrolling stopped (or at least slowed to free resources).

Comment: Maybe you're talking about [DeferLoadStrategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204785.aspx) for UWP? Haha I'm a little curious what you're talking about now also. +1

Comment: @ChrisW. No, that was not it, but what I was looking for was referenced on that page too... [x:Phase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204790.aspx) but that too is only for UWP. I guess my memory is not what it was and I thought that was for WPF!